# NOt returning to fragment after a web service call to load images

Tags: android, web-services, gridview, imageview

Below is the fragment that i use to populate images

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    View inflatedView                   = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picture_grid, container, false);

    this.gridView                       = (GridView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    this.myImageAdapater                = new DeviceImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), bundle.getString("id"), bundle.getString("name"));
```

I am using a custom adapter to set to the grid view and have written certain methods to call the webservices. After a response is received from webservice I dont return to the calling fragment. Please help. I am new to android development.

Comment: If you never return from `DeviceImageAdapter` then probably there is some error inside that class. Do you get any crash or message on the logcat? Could you provide the code of that class too? By the way are you setting the adapter to the `GridView`?

Comment: Yes i am setting the adapter

Comment: I am calling a webservice from the DEviceImage adapter class and I get the result back till there.

Comment: I see in the log that even before i get a response i move back and forth to the fragment and finally on receiving the response move to main activity

Comment: Without the code it is really hard to say what is wrong.. Can you provide it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had to do some work around for it. I send the fragment and grid view as arguments to the custom adapter and later after i get the response call that method that sets the gridview and fragment and does the code that was suppose to do after response has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the fragment was not called after receiving a web service response. For that teh work around that i found is:

1. Pass Fragment and gridview as arguments to the custom adapter.
2. And once I receive the response from the webserver,I am calling a method that is supposed to be executed after receiving a response and I am passing the fragment and the gridview to it.

Also i dont know if its the best solution but its working..:)